# SQL Select results in 0 rows only if I use a date or date range

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle

So I've been stuck on this for awhile because every statement I came up with I would test in SQL Developer and it worked fine, pulling over 300 rows.  However would error in VB.NET saying 0 rows exist.

```
SELECT DISTINCT mti_part_no,sum(mpcs.shop_inv_history.quantity) As FebQTY 
FROM mpcs.shop_inventory, mpcs.shop_inv_history 
WHERE shop_inv_history.DATE_TIME BETWEEN '" & DT1.Text & "' AND '" & DT2.Text & "' AND
      shop_inv_history.comments = 'CHECK ITEM OUT' AND mpcs.shop_inventory.si_key=mpcs.shop_inv_history.si_key AND
      SHOP_INVENTORY.CATEGORY BETWEEN 900 and 999 AND SHOP_INVENTORY.SCRAP_FLAG <> 1 
GROUP BY mti_part_no 
ORDER BY FebQTY DESC
```

Now, I have tried the date more vague as `Like '%Feb%'` or more precise as `05-Feb-15`

All of these pull rows just fine in SQL Developer but produce 0 rows in VB.  I also tried it in C# just in case and the results were the same.

The moment I take the date out of the equation all together, I get data just fine in VB.

I'm at a loss here.

Here is the statement as it is sent when ran and when copied over to SQl Dev produces 1,022 rows

```
    SELECT DISTINCT mpcs.shop_inventory.MTI_PART_NO,
     SUM(mpcs.shop_inv_history.QUANTITY) AS FebQTY
    FROM mpcs.shop_inventory,
    mpcs.shop_inv_history
WHERE mpcs.shop_inventory.SI_KEY = mpcs.shop_inv_history.SI_KEY
AND mpcs.shop_inv_history.DATE_TIME BETWEEN '22-Jun-2015' AND '14-Sep-2016'
AND mpcs.shop_inv_history.COMMENTS = 'CHECK ITEM OUT'
AND mpcs.shop_inventory.CATEGORY BETWEEN 900 AND 999
AND mpcs.shop_inventory.SCRAP_FLAG <> 1
GROUP BY mpcs.shop_inventory.MTI_PART_NO
ORDER BY FebQTY DESC
```

[image]

Comment: what is the value of DT1.Text and DT2.Text?

Comment: Use parameters.

Comment: First, use bind variables.  Don't dynamically assemble SQL statements. If you decide that you really want to avoid bind variables and make your code slower, less secure, and more error prone, you'd want to use a `to_date` with an explicit format mask that matches whatever format your variables have.

Comment: Are you sure that the data type of the field in your database is actually a DATETIME?  Make sure you are actually doing a date compare and not a character compare.  You might also want to explicitly cast the values in DT1 and DT2 to datetime.  Are you sure the dates are in the right order (begin date in DT1.Text and end date in DT2.Text)?  If the order of the dates is flip flopped then you will get nothing.

Comment: Akshey: Its a datetimepicker, its fine, as this happens with manually entered dates also.
Justin: DT does have a format mask. Its fine.
 David: Yes, I am sure.

Remember, even when I manually use a date in the select statement, it fails.  BUT works in SQL Developer so the string I don't see the problem with.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your code, run it in the debugger, and paste the actual SQL statement being created by your app so that we can see exactly what is being sent to the server.

Comment: @dazedandconfused I've added it to the post.

Comment: Any thoughts, ideas?

Comment: I took a long head hurting Google journey the past 24 hours and I still cannot find what I am doing wrong here that causes this only to fail in .NET